# MAMP slim nginx 404

Tags: nginx, mamp, slim

When I was using slim3.x with MAMA nginx, I came across with 404 error.
My `routes/public/index.php` code is from here: [First Application Walkthrough](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/tutorial/first-app.html).

My directory is : `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/slimpro/routes/public/index.php`

[image]

and I add

```
location /slimpro {
    root /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/slimpro/routes;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /public/index.php?$query_string;
}
```

to 
`/Applications/MAMP/conf/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
server {

}
```

How can I solve this 404 error?

Answer (score 0):

in  nginx  you should edit your  nginx conf file  .

```
   if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php last;
}
```

In  apache server ,you should edit the conf

you can add  the rewrite rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-F
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```